# mpmovie player didexitfulscreen notification not working in ios

Tags: ios, webview, ios8, mpmovieplayer

I am loading a youtube video in a webview. As my app is a online radio app, the radio plays in the background. When I click on the webview it redirects the video in full screen mode in mpmovieplayer. What I want is when someone click on the webview or when the mpmovieplayer starts playing video, the radio should pause. But how can I track when mpmoviepayer starts playing and exiting full scrren. I also set the notification MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification in my `viewdidload` method. But it never has been called.

```
self.videoTitleLabel.text = videoInfo.videoTitle;

//NSString *vidUrl = [videoInfo.videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

CGSize scrSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;//appDel.window.frame.size;

float imgSclToX = scrSize.width/16.0;

int imgWidth = (int) (scrSize.width -18);
int imgHeight = (int) ((float)(9.0)*imgSclToX);

// DebugLog(@"Yo-----> Window: %@ Width: %i Height: %i", NSStringFromCGSize(scrSize), imgWidth, imgHeight);

NSString *htmlStr = @"";
// htmlStr = [htmlStr stringByAppendingFormat:@"<iframe width=\"%i\" height=\"%i\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", imgWidth, imgHeight, vidUrl];

NSString *tStr = videoInfo.videoURL;
// NSString *tStr = @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yz_j7nVCJJ0";
tStr = [tStr substringFromIndex:([tStr rangeOfString:@"v="].location+2)];

htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe  type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%i\" height=\"%i\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", imgWidth, imgHeight, tStr];

NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body>%@<p><b>Artist:</b> %@<br><b>Composer:</b>%@<p>%@</p></body></html>", htmlStr, videoInfo.videoArtist, videoInfo.videoCompositor, videoInfo.videoDescription];
[self.myWebview loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];

if([appDelegate.lastState isEqualToString:@"play"])
{
    [appDelegate pausePlayer];
    manuallyPause = YES;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem... Notifications

(UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification, 
UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification, 
MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification, 
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification) 

 not work properly on iOS 8. 
On iOS 7 handling these events works fine!

Comment: update: MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification and MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification work fine.

Answer (score 0):

See answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263803/1756448 (by **user1717750**) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26096400/1756448 (by **Selvin**).

Use AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification in conjunction with UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification and UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification for iOS 8
instead of UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification.

It works for me! )