# Rotate youtube video with iOS8

Tags: uiwebview, rotation, ios8, ios8.1

I am having a problem with rotate youtube video. I added the following code to my app. And it works for iOS 7. However, it doesn't for iOS8.

In my view controller, I used the following code:

```
     if(IS_OS_6_OR_LATER){ 
        // I use the following notification for iOS 7
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) latername:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];//Notification

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];//Notification
                }    



if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) { 
// I use the following notification for iOS 8
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:self.view.window];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:self.view.window];
        }



 -(void) youTubeStarted:(NSNotification*) notif {
    //Handle event 
            AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = YES;
            NSLog(@"start fullscreen");
        }
        -(void) youTubeFinished:(NSNotification*) notif {
            AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];//Notification
            appDelegate.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying = NO;//Notification
            NSLog(@"exit fullscreen");//Notification
        }



 -(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    //Handle rotate
            NSLog(@"AutoState");
            return NO;
        }
        -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    //Handle rotate
            NSLog(@"AutoState 1");
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;//Notification
        }
        - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    //Handle rotate
            NSLog(@"AutoState 2");
            return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;//Notification
        }
```

In iOS 7, when video is played in Landscape mode, I press Done button, I see log 'AutoState 1' is shown however I don't see this log when running with iOS 8. Can you help me resolve this on iOS 8? Thank you very much

Comment: Please take time to correctly format your code so it is easier to read. Provide more information about your problem and it's context.

Comment: @gareththegeek: Sorry because I am newbie. I am so sorry about this

Comment: Who can help me? Please!!!!!!!

Comment: anybody!!!!help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification not work in iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561812/uimovieplayercontrollerdidenterfullscreennotification-not-work-in-ios8)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of limiting the entire app to Portrait and then trying to make the video player allow landscape, you should instead allow landscape all over your app and then limit your invididual view controllers (or the root view controller) to only allow Portrait mode, like this:

In the target settings, allow landscape for your app:

[image]

In your view controller(s), add this to limit it to portrait orientation:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```